# Mapping hierarchial objects in MongoDB using Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, odm

Let's say I have an entity in MongoDB which stores a list of employees.

```
@Entitiy
public class EmployeeList{
    @Embedded
    List<Employee> employeeList;
}
```

Employee is an abstract class with some properties.

```
public abstract class Employee{
    String name;
    String emailId;
}
```

There are different types of employees - Developer, Designer, HumanResource

```
class Developer extends Employee{
    String githubProfile;
}


class Designer extends Employee{
   String portfolio;
}


class HumanResource extends Employee{
   String department; 
}
```

If mongo contains a list of developers, designers and humanResource people, can Morphia map them to their corresponding classes?
For example, if the db has the following data -

```
[{'name':'p1', 'emailId':'p1@x1", 'portfolio':'http://abc.co'},
{'name':'p2', 'emailId':'p2@x1", 'department':'finance'},
{'name':'p3', 'emailId':'p3@x1", 'githubProfile':'http://github.com/p3'}]
```

When this collections is mapped by Morphia onto `EmployeeList` entity, how do I make sure they are mapped to their corresponding classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding employees to the list then probably you would be doing something like below.

```
employeeList.add(new Developer(...))
employeeList.add(new Designer(...))
employeeList.add(new HumanResource(...))
```

Then save the entity in morphia and it should work.

PS: I have not tried this.